# Redirect website based on day of week

Tags: php, redirect

I would like to redirect my website on a certain day of a week.
I've used the following code, but it won't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<?php 
 $day = date("D");
 if( ($day == "Mon") )
  {
header("Location: monday.html");
  exit(); }
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: When you debug, what is the runtime value of `$day`?  In what way does this code "not work"?

Comment: The code works fine...

Comment: Set top of file `ini_set("display_errors",1)` because of check ny `header ` warning.

Comment: don't use `echo` before `header("Location: monday.html");` check this. if you used `echo` before header then remove

Comment: down voted this as there is no sufficient information to help you. please provide an error log and/or any additional info that may help us help you

Comment: The Code Okay..have You any error?

Comment: I used the code for my Wordpress website. All I get is a blank white page.

Comment: So please write something for test and check that monday.html  page.

Answer (score 1):

Make it like this. This way you can easily adjust the Links and you don't even need if/else.

```
$redirects = array(1 => 'monday.html',   // Link for Monday
                   2 => 'tuestday.html', // Link for Tuesday
                   3 => 'day.html',      // foo
                   4 => 'day.html',      // foo
                   5 => 'day.html',      // foo
                   6 => 'day.html',      // foo
                   7 => 'sunday.html');  // Link for Sunday

header('Location: '.$redirects[date(N)]);
exit();
```

Comment: With this code I get a blank page either. I put the code in the header.php file of my Wordpress website between the <head> and </head> tags.

Comment: Do you get an Error? Do you have an Output before header()?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.

What I did wrong was put the code in the header.php file of my Wordpress website.
Now it's in the functions.php and it works fine.

Thanks for all the quick replies.

Comment: Putting code direct in functions.php file without attached to any hook is bad practice and it should be avoided.

Answer (score -2):

Add code to init hook.

```
add_action('init', 'redirectDay');

function redirectDay(){
 $redirects = array(1 => 'monday.html',   // Link for Monday
               2 => 'tuestday.html', // Link for Tuesday
               3 => 'day.html',      // foo
               4 => 'day.html',      // foo
               5 => 'day.html',      // foo
               6 => 'day.html',      // foo
               7 => 'sunday.html');  // Link for Sunday

             wp_redirect($redirects[date(N)]);
             exit();
}
```

Comment: Right, just for writing it clear added as answer instead of comment, Thanks to you! I checked it's working.